# HMR/Live Reload with Webpack 5 Dev Server

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, webpack-5

I am trying to get the HMR/Live reload feature of webpack to work but while 'watching' files seems to work, the refresh of the browser won't happen.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.htm$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9000,
        index: './homepage.htm',
        host: 'test.local',
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        hot: true,
        watchContentBase: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css'
        }),
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.45.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

Command:

```
"serve": "webpack serve --mode=development --env=development"
```

The output from webpack when watching and recompiling is:

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 880 bytes [cached] 1 asset
assets by chunk 422 KiB (name: main)
  asset main.js 420 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
  asset main.ddfc292cf943c7bbaef7.hot-update.js 1.56 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main)
  asset style.css 410 bytes [emitted] (name: main)
asset main.ddfc292cf943c7bbaef7.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint main 422 KiB (880 bytes) = style.css 410 bytes main.js 420 KiB main.ddfc292cf943c7bbaef7.hot-update.js 1.56 KiB 1 auxiliary asset
cached modules 340 KiB [cached] 36 modules
runtime modules 29.3 KiB 14 modules
modules by layer 372 bytes (javascript) 77 bytes (css/mini-extract)
  ./src/style.scss 372 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.scss 77 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.45.1 compiled successfully in 99 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Noticely there is no `[HMR]` entries (which I think I should see despite it notifiying me that the hot-update files are updated.) Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should initially see these messages in your browser console:

```
[Log] [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[Info] [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[Info] [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

You need to enable your code for hmr by putting these lines in your index.js:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

Look here for documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/